# How to pick up updated user input values while dynamically editing rows of table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, erb

I am trying to dynamically edit rows of a table using Javascript and JQuery.

Expected Functionality -
There is an edit link at the end of each row in table. When user presses this link, the text of tr element gets replaced with the corresponding html content for input. At the same time, the edit link gets converted to a Save link. When user presses this save link after editing, I want to pick up the updated values in input, create a form and post it.

Problem - 
Traversing DOM for a table row does not give the new user input values, but picks up the older data.

Any pointers on how can I pick up the new values that user has entered ?

Kindly check the Save() function in the code. This is a part of my .erb file.

PS : Is there a neater way to achieve this functionality ?

Thanks!

```
<table id = "documents_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> document ID </th>
      <th> document Link </th>
      <th> document Status </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <%= @documents.each do |document| %>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> <%= document[:document_id] %> </td>
      <td> <%= document[:document_link] %> </td>
      <td> <%= document[:document_status] %> </td>
      <td> <%= link_to "Edit", {}, {:class => "editLink"} %> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <% end %>

 <script type="text/javascript">

 $(".editLink").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var tableRow = $(this).parent().parent();

  var documentId = tableRow.children("td:nth-child(1)");
  var documentLink = tableRow.children("td:nth-child(2)");
  var documentStatus = tableRow.children("td:nth-child(3)");
  var actionLink = tableRow.children("td:nth-child(4)");

  documentId.html("<input type='text' value='" + documentId.html() + "'/>");
  documentLink.html("<input type='text' value='" + documentLink.html() + "'/>");
  documentStatus.html("<select><option value='On-Hold'> On-Hold </option> <option value='Submitted'> Submitted </option> </select>");
  documentAction.html("<input type='text' value='" + documentAction.html() + "'/>");
  actionLink.html("<a class='saveLink' href='/inspection/save'> Save </a>");

  $('.saveLink').bind("click", Save);
});

function Save(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // Problematic code -> picks up previous <tr> data instead of new one

  var updatedTableRow = $(this).parent().parent();
  alert(updatedTableRow.html());
  var documentId = updatedTableRow.children("td:nth-child(1):input");
  var documentLink = updatedTableRow.children("td:nth-child(2):input");
  var documentStatus = updatedTableRow.children("td:nth-child(3)");

  var params = { document_id : documentId.val(),
                document_link : documentLink.html(),
                document_status : documentStatus.html()}
  var path = "/inspection/save"
  postForm(path, params);
};
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried using classes on the inputs? I usually accomplish this type of thing like this. var value = $(this).closest("tr").find('input.myValue').val()

Comment: Is this just for learning? If not then I would suggest looking into AngularJs which will simplify this kind of stuff a LOT. Have done many of these dynamic tables with Angular and it's a breeze compared to vanilla JS.

Comment: @kurt I tried your suggestion. Doesn't pick up the new values entered by user.

Answer (score 0):

I think u need to replace `this` with `event.target`

```
var tableRow = $(event.target).parent().parent();
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Thanks for suggestion though.

Comment: when u do alert(updatedTableRow.html()); are u sure it shows older data?

Comment: Yes, it shows older data. Infact I am posting this data into another view, where the older data shows up.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use DOM ID's on the TR's.
Store that ID which is selected for edit in your .editLink click handler, to always know which row is under edit. In your Save function you can easily get the correct row like this:

```
var updatedTableRow = $(obj.trIdUnderEdit);
```

Comment: The problem is not with accessing the correct row. I can still access the correct row. The actual problem is that while traversing the tr element, the new values entered by user are not picked up, and older values show up.